# Fragments and Activities using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have the following activity with two integers

```
class ComplexActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var clubs : Int = 0
    var diamonds : Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_complex)

    val fragment = ClubsFragment()
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment)
    transaction.commit()

    }
}
```

I want to change the value of the integer clubs from the fragment ClubsFragment when isScored is true

```
class ClubsFragment : Fragment(),  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

private var isScored = false



override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    val v = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clubs, container, false)

    v.image_clubs.setOnClickListener {

        if(isScored){
           activity.clubs = 4
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use activity.clubs but It's not working. How can I access the activity constants from a fragment.

Comment: Try with companion object

Comment: @MeLine Did not make a diffrenece

Comment: copanioin object{ var clubs = 0} is equivalent to static in java

Comment: @MeLine but when I try to access it from the fragment using activity.clubs it does not show up

Comment: did you try to make it public ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to accomplish. But another approach could be something like this: Communicate with an activity from your fragment via an interface. Refer to the Android Docs: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 3):

You would create an interface, let's say `FragmentListener` for your Activity that contains a function like `fun updateClubs(count: Int)`. Your Activity should implement this interface.
Then, in your Fragment, add a fragmentListener property and override onAttach(context: Context):

```
private var fragmentListener: FragmentListener? = null

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    this.listener = context as? FragmentListener
}
```

Then, in your OnClickListener, you can simply call `fragmentListener?.updateClubs(4)`.